# Is there anyway to assign name to ArrayList/Any Object using a String variable?

Tags: java, arraylist, naming-conventions

I'm working on a problem I found from `exercism.io`. I creating a database for a school involving student with their respective information. I came up with a solution that could possibly work, but I'm not sure if it syntactically possible.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Student {
    String name;
    Integer grade;

    public Student(String name, Integer grade) {
        this.name = name;
        this.grade = grade;
    }
}
```

I want to keep track of grades created using a `ArrayList` that contains an `int` for each grade, without creating an entire k-12 realistic school setup. I want to add the grades as needed. So when adding a new student I'm checking if the gradeList contains the students grade, if not I create that grade. What I want to do is convert the student's grade to a `String`, and use that `String` as the name of the `ArrayList`.

Is this possible?

```
public class School {
    Student current;
    ArrayList<Integer> gradeList;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Student>> database;

    public School() {
        gradeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        database = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Student>>();
    }

    public void createGrade(Integer grade) {
        String addingGrade = Integer.toString(grade);
        ArrayList<Student> addingGrade
    }

    public void add(Student newS) {
        if (!gradeList.contains(newS.grade)) {
            createGrade(newS.grade);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You need to store more information about the grade - on which course it was given. Otherwise, if a student graded 100 twice - you wont know to tell on which course he got it. What is the logic to store the grade under Student? Create a new class Grade - and store the student and course inside it. than the creation would become easy - you will check if grade exists for student and course

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, grade is the grade/year the student is in.

Comment: How many grades can there be? Just create them all on start up whether they are used or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a map is a better way:

```
Map<String , ArrayList<Student>> map;
    public void createGrade(Integer grade) {
        if (map == null) {
            map = new HashMap<String , ArrayList<Student>>();
        }
        ArrayList<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
        //...
        //list.add(student1);
        //list.add(student1);
        //...
        // todo add student
        String addingGrade = Integer.toString(grade);
        map.put(addingGrade , list);
    }
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, I'm still a student, and I haven't learned much of Maps in java. Are they any semblance of a dictionary in java?

Comment: @Swanson7 Yes, they're about the same. When in doubt, check [the dock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Comment: @JornVernee Thanks